# Is there any significant performance benefits with HTTP2 multiplexing as compared with HTTP2 Server Push?

Tags: http2, server-push

HTTP2 multiplexing uses the same TCP connection thereby removing Connection time to the same host.

But with HTTP2 Server Push is there any significant performance benefits except for the roundtrip time that HTTP2 multiplexing will take while requesting every resource.

Answer (score 2):

I gave a presentation about this, that you can find [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpLtBftqM04).

In particular, the demo (starting at [36:37](https://youtu.be/QpLtBftqM04?t=2201)) shows the benefits that you can have with multiplexing alone, and then by adding HTTP/2 Push.

Spoiler: the combination of HTTP/2 multiplexing and Push yields astonishing better results with respect to HTTP/1.1.

Then again, every case is different, so you have to actually measure your case.
But the potential of HTTP/2 to yield better performance than HTTP/1.1 is really large, and many (most?) cases will benefit from this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you're asking here, or if it's a good fit for StackOverflow but will attempt to answer none-the-less. If this is not the answer you are looking for then please rephrase the question so we can understand what exactly it is you are looking for.

You are right in that HTTP/2 uses multiplexing, which does negate the need for multiple connections (and the time and resources needed to set them up and manage them). However it's much more than that as it's not limited (browsers will typically limit connections to 4-6 per host) and also allows for "similar" connections (same IP and same certificate but different hostname) to share connections as well. Basically it solves the queuing of resources that the request/response method of HTTP/1 means and reduces need of limited multiple connections that HTTP/1 requires as a workaround. Which  also reduces need for other workarounds like sharding, sprite files, concatenation... etc.

And yes HTTP/2 server push saves on one round trip. So when you request a webpage it sends both the HTML and the CSS needed to draw the page as the server knows you will need the CSS as it's pointless just sending you the HTML, waiting for your web browser to get it, parse it, see it needs CSS and request the CSS file and wait for it to download.

I'm not sure if you're implying that a round trip time is so low, that there is little gains in HTTP/2 server push because there is now no delay in requesting a file due to HTTP/2 multiplexing? If so that is not the case - there are significant gains to be made in pushing resources, particularly blocking resources like CSS which the browser will wait for before drawing a single thing on screen. While multiplexing reduces the delay in sending a request, it does not reduce the latency on the request travelling to the server, now on the server responding to that and sending it back. While these sound small they are noticeable and make a website feel slow.

So yes, at present, the primary gain for HTTP/2 Server Push is in reducing that round trip time (basically to zero for key resources).

However we are at the infancy of this and there are potential other uses for performance or other reasons. For example you could use this as a way of prioritising content so an important image could be pushed early when, without this, a browser would likely request CSS and Javascript first and leave images until later. Server Push could also negate the need for inline CSS (which bloats pages with copies of style sheets and may require Javascript to then load the proper CSS file) - another HTTP/1.1 workaround for performance. I think it will be very interesting to watch what happens with HTTP/2 Server Push over the coming years.

Saying that, there still some significant challenges with HTTP/2 server push. Most importantly how do you prevent wasting bandwidth by pushing resources that the browser already has cached? It's likely a digest HTTP header will be added for this but still under discussion. Which leads on how to implement HTTP/2 Server Push in the best method - for web browsers, web servers and web developers? The [HTTP/2 spec](http://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#PushResources) is a bit vague on how this should be implemented, which leaves it up to different web servers in particular providing different methods to signal to the server to push a resource.

As I say, I think this one of the parts of HTTP/2 that could lead to some very interesting applications. We live in interesting times...